# Maximo/Oracle SQL statement returning unwanted data from joined tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, maximo

Pretty sure it's a simple fix, but I'm lost.  Trying to pull data from joined tables where there's a checkbox = 1 (gditwocertflag).  I only want to see the specific row that's checked.  But I'm pulling every labor row from work orders that meet specificed criteria with that block being checked.  I've tried to join different ways with the same result, so I'm pretty sure it's not the join that's the issue. Also tried a nested select that errored on the sub query returning more than 1 row.  Here's where I'm at right now.  Is it how I'm calling it?

```
select w.wonum, l.laborcode as certifier
from maximo.workorder W, maximo.labtrans L
where w.wonum = l.refwo
and w.status = 'CLOSE'
and w.gditperformingrcc like ('MDKM%')
and w.gditusertype = 'PMEL'
and w.wonum not like ('QA%')
and l.gditwocertflag = '1'
and parent is null
and (w.actfinish >= trunc(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'MM') 
and w.actfinish  < trunc(add_months(sysdate, -0), 'MM'))
;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: You are saying that you are getting rows with this query for which `l.gditwocertflag = '1'` is not true? Addd this to your select clause: `select w.wonum, l.laborcode as certifier, l.gditwocertflag`. Are you really getting rows where the flag is not 1?

Comment: Thank you.  I added the certflag and noticed they were indeed all 1, which made no sense.  Our database ties into  2 other locations and the multiple entries were coincidentally where we had a matching work order number (which I was told would never happen).  I filtered the other 2 locations and that fixed the issue.  I never would've guessed that would have happened.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help.  Problem solved.  We share a database with two other locations and I didn't filter them out specifically.  I thought the filters I had would have done the trick.  However, it didn't.  And coincidentally they have the some work order numbers that match some of ours, which isn't supposed to happen.  Which is why it appeared I was returning incorrect data.  I've been scratching my head at this for the last two days...

Answer (score 0):

If GDITWOCERTFLAG is a YORN field in Maximo you should be using an Integer value to compare:

```
select w.wonum, l.laborcode as certifier
from maximo.workorder W
join maximo.labtrans L
on w.wonum = l.refwo
and l.gditwocertflag = 1
where w.status = 'CLOSE'
and w.gditperformingrcc like ('MDKM%')
and w.gditusertype = 'PMEL'
and w.wonum not like ('QA%')
and parent is null
and (w.actfinish >= trunc(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'MM') 
and w.actfinish  < trunc(add_months(sysdate, -0), 'MM'))
;
```

Comment: Still have the same issue.  The labor record (labtrans table) allows multiple users to enter labor on the work order (wonum).  However, only 1 person can certify the work.  Once the certflag is checked, nobody else can check it.  So there may be multiple labor rows, but only 1 per wonum with that block checked.  Hope that makes sense.  Right now I'm returning duplicate wonums for each labor entry.

Comment: Got it, so you needed to add the Site ID to the Join condition?

Comment: I did.  I had it in my initial statement but I took it out along with some other stuff before posting it just to shorten it down some.  What I didn't do, was add w.siteid and l.siteid.  I only filtered for w.  So it was pulling L data from all sites.  We recently did a consolidation and now multiple sites share a database.  This was never an issue before.  Just not used to multiple sites sharing a database...lol.